# Unique alphanumeric String with a fixed length

Tags: java

How can generate an **unique** alphanumeric String with a **fixed length** of 8 characters. I want base it in an Id + current time.
I tried with MD5 but it make a string too long

Thanks!

Comment: Any attempts from your side ??

Comment: What do you mean by unique?

Comment: What about getting first or last 8 characters of the MD5 hash? (Or any other hash like SHA1, SHA256 etc...)

Comment: @bgamlath first or last characters will be unique always?

Comment: @Bathsheba I mean that never will get a repeated string

Comment: Per session of *genuinely* never?

Comment: @Bathsheba in my database

Comment: In which case, can't you use an automatically generated primary key?

Comment: @xedo: A good hash function will almost always give you unique value. But it is not guaranteed. After all, you can only have finitely many 8 character strings.

Comment: @Bathsheba because is to make a public url, and an id is too evident

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that 8 alphanumeric characters is most likely too few to guarantee uniqueness ... using that approach.

You just need to do some arithmetic.  Multiply the number of ids that your application could generate per second by the expected number of seconds that your application is expected to "live".  Now figure out how many alphanumeric characters you need to encode that number ... and that gives you how large the "timestamp" part of your id would need to be.  Then add the characters for the "id" part of your string.

IMO, the best approach (if you have to use short strings) is to generate partially or fully random strings, and then check them against a (big) table of all previously issued id strings.  If you get a collision, generate another string, and repeat.

---

If you also want your ids to be hard to predict (per your comment), then the "random number" approach is best.  Make sure that you use a cryptographic-quality RNG or PRNG.  The problem with a timestamp-based approach is that the resulting ids will be much easier to predict ... or guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`java.util.UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String id = uuid.toString().substring(0, 8);
```

Comment: A substring of a random UUID has a much higher probability of being non-unique.  In this case, there are only `16^8` == `2 ^ 32` possible values.  That means each ID has a chance of 1 in 4 billion of having previously been generated.  That's probably unacceptably high ... unless you do some other checks.

Answer (score 1):

Strings can't be unique: uniqueness refers to an item **in the context** of a collection without duplicates, called a *set*. Given a set of symbols (you said alphanumeric in you question) and a string length (in your example 8) there's a known number of possible combinations which may or may not be enough for your needs.

Your requirements can't be satisfied (at least, not with the information you provided). If you really want the token to be unique **and** the given input (id, timestamp) is guaranteed to be the key (ie for each given ID you'll never have two or more identical timestamps), just put the ID and the timestamp side by side.

The size of the ID columns will be the maximum size for the username + the fixed size for the timestamp.